# JRE: There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue

Tags: java, memory, jvm, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am running a Java application in a Linux Server with 32GB of memory and suddenly the application stopped working and returned this error in a log file. At the moment of the exception there was still about 25GB of memory available.

These were the details at the moment of the crash:

```
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 12288 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# Possible reasons:
#   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
#   The process is running with CompressedOops enabled, and the Java Heap may be blocking the growth of the native heap
# Possible solutions:
#   Reduce memory load on the system
#   Increase physical memory or swap space
#   Check if swap backing store is full
#   Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
#   Decrease number of Java threads
#   Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
#   Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
#   JVM is running with Zero Based Compressed Oops mode in which the Java heap is
#     placed in the first 32GB address space. The Java Heap base address is the
#     maximum limit for the native heap growth. Please use -XX:HeapBaseMinAddress
#     to set the Java Heap base and to place the Java Heap above 32GB virtual address.
# This output file may be truncated or incomplete.
#
#  Out of Memory Error (os_linux.cpp:2798), pid=505585, tid=0x00007f80491d7640
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_342-b07) (build 1.8.0_342-8u342-b07-0ubuntu1~22.04-b07)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.342-b07 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#

Memory: 4k page, physical 32875188k(25987732k free), swap 0k(0k free)

vm_info: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.342-b07) for linux-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_342-8u342-b07-0ubuntu1~22.04-b07), built on Jul 23 2022 16:13:07 by "buildd" with gcc 11.2.0
```

This message contains some possible solutions. But instead of trying each one of those solutions and cross my fingers for it to no happen again, I need to determine the exact reason why this OutOfMemory happened, try to reproduce it again and apply the correct solution.

I am starting an Apache Felix instance and the command line I use to start the java app is:

```
java -Dorg.osgi.framework.bootdelegation=sun.*,com.sun.* -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar bin/felix.jar &
```

Comment: The log doesn't contain much information. Do you have full error details available? Can you share them? Did the app crash or became unresponsive only?

Comment: @JurajMartinka Yes, the app crashed (closed). you may find more details about the error above in the new edited post. The rest of the file are memory addresses and irrelevant stuff.

Comment: Can you give more details about your java app and the environment? How exactly do you run it (docker or simple java app running on the host)? What JVM properties do you set?

Comment: @JurajMartinka Please, see updated question with command line.

Comment: So I assume you run this command directly on the host and are running it manually without any sort of orchestrator (systemd or similar). The JVM by default, should request 1/4 of available RAM as MaxHeapSize - since you don't pass `-Xmx`, it should be about 8 GB. It's not clear to me why the problem happens but maybe you can set `ulimit -c unlimited` as the error message says and also provide more diagnostic info as produced by `jcmd VM.info` the next time you run it(not sure if available in Java 8). Finally, I would really suggest updating to JDK 17, or at least 11.